# YAML: Mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 4 column 5

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-static-web-app

This throws an error, any yaml experts can see why?

All my spaces and indentations seem to be correct:

```
trigger:​
  - develop

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest​
​
steps:​
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true

  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0​
    inputs:​
      app_location: "/" ​
      api_location: "api​"
      output_location: ""
    env:​
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your lines have the unicode character [U+200B (zero width space)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) at the end of the line. Remove these characters, YAML doesn't recognize them as separation spaces, which is why parsing fails.